# On the maximum elements of a numerical semigroup that have order between $n$ and $2n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a submonoid of the non-negative integers $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}.$ If $\mathbb Z_{\geq 0} \setminus S$ is finite, we say that $S$ is a *numerical semigroup*. Let $S^*$ denote the collection of nonzero elements of $S.$ Observe that $S \supsetneq S^* \supseteq \{s + t \mid s \in S^* \text{ and } t \in S\} = S^* + S,$ hence $S^*$ is a *proper ideal* of $S$; it contains every proper ideal of $S,$ i.e., $S^*$ is the *maximal ideal* of $S.$

Generally, if $n$ is a non-negative integer, then the $n$-fold sum of $S^*$ is given by $nS^* = \{s_1 + \cdots + s_n \mid s_1, \dots, s_n \in S^*\}.$ One can verify that for each positive integer $n,$ the sets $nS^* \setminus (n + 1) S^*$ are finite, and the collection $S^* \setminus 2S^*$ constitutes the unique minimal system of generators of $S^*.$ Even more, there are strict containments $(n + 1) S^* \subsetneq nS^*$ for each integer $n \geq 1,$ hence it follows that $$nS^* \setminus 2nS^* = \bigcup_{i = n}^{2n - 1} [iS^* \setminus (i + 1) S^*].$$ Consequently, we have that $\max[(2n - 1) S^* \setminus 2nS^*] \leq \max(nS^* \setminus 2nS^*).$

> **Question.** Does $\max(nS^* \setminus 2nS^*) \leq \max[(2n - 1) S^* \setminus 2nS^*]$ hold?

Based on a large number of random trials using the `numericalsgps` package of the GAP System, it seems that the answer is yes; however, the intuition is unclear: more summands does not necessarily gives rise to a larger positive integer.

To be precise, suppose that $S^* \setminus 2S^* = \{s_1, \dots, s_k\}.$ Every element of $S$ can be written as $a_1 s_1 + \cdots + a_k s_k$ for some (not necessarily unique) non-negative integers $a_1, \dots, a_k$; the vector $(a_1, \dots, a_k)$ is called an $S$-*factorization*, and its *length* is $a_1 + \cdots + a_k.$ E.g., if $S^* \setminus 2S^* = \{10, 11, 34\},$ then $44 = 10 + 34 = 4 \cdot 11$ has the $S$-factorizations $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(0, 4, 0)$ of respective lengths two and four. We define $\operatorname{ord}_S(s) = \max \{a_1 + \cdots + a_k \mid (a_1, \dots, a_k) \text{ is an } S \text{-factorization of } s\}$; in the previous example, we have that $\operatorname{ord}_S(44) = 4.$

Using this terminology, we may rephrase the above question.

> **Question.** Does $\operatorname{ord}_S(\max(nS^* \setminus 2nS^*)) = 2n - 1$ hold? Put another way, must $\max(nS^* \setminus 2nS^*)$ admit an $S$-factorization of length $2n - 1$?

Even under this interpretation, the question is quite subtle. I would appreciate any comments or suggestions. Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I realize now that I made a typo in the GAP code; the answer is no.

Even for $S^* \setminus 2S^* = \{10, 11, 34\},$ there is a counterexample. One can verify that $79 = 1 \cdot 11 + 2 \cdot 34$ is the unique factorization of $79$ in $S,$ hence we have that $79 \in 3S^* \setminus 4S^*.$ Even more, $79$ satisfies $79 = \max(2S^* \setminus 4S^*)$ and $79 = \max(3S^* \setminus 6S^*),$ i.e., $\max(3S^* \setminus 6S^*) > \max(5S^* \setminus 6S^*).$